# Can I use hook_css_alter inside of hook_form_alter

Tags: 8, forms

Can I use hook_css_alter inside of hook_form_alter. I need to unset a css file only on certain forms and only to non-admins. This is what I have but it doesn't work.

```
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Session\AccountInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Session\UserSession;

function mymodule_form_alter(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state,  $form_id) {
  $user = \Drupal::currentUser()->getRoles();
    if(in_array("administrator", $user)) {

    function mymodule_css_alter(&$css) {
      unset($css['core/themes/stable/css/system/components/tabledrag.module.css']);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Short answer: no. You cannot do this.

Comment: Longer answer...that inner function only exists within the scope of the form alter function (or even the if block, is that even syntactically allowed in php?), so it's a "no" at the language level before Drupal gets involved. Finding some context from the request in a global hook_css_alter that lets you identify the page and unset accordingly would be an option, but I suspect there'll be something more elegant in D8

Answer (score 4):

You can't use a hook function inside of a hook function. If you are in the css alter hook you have to get the information you need from where you are in code. For example you could check for the route name of the form because the current route match is available in a service. So this could work (not tested):

```
function mymodule_css_alter(&$css) {
  $user = \Drupal::currentUser()->getRoles();
  $route = \Drupal::service('current_route_match')->getRouteName();
  if (in_array('administrator', $user) && $route == 'entity.node.edit_form') {
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried this but it didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Yo unset CSS files on certain pages for certain users, you could do something like this:

```
function hook_css_alter(&$css, \Drupal\Core\Asset\AttachedAssetsInterface $assets) {
   if (\Drupal::routeMatch()->getRouteName() == 'form.route') {
    $roles = \Drupal::currentUser()->getRoles();
    if(!in_array("administrator", $roles)){
       unset($css['file.css']);
    }
  }
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks, I tried this but it didn't work.

Comment: I suppose you are doing something wrong then... This should definitely work